# Ubuntu 16.04 won't start with linux-image-4.4.0-119-generic

Tags: boot, grub2, kernel

My ubuntu 16.04 computer has stopped booting following an update, which updated to `linux-image-4.4.0-119-generic`. It will only start if I go into advanced grub options and select the previous linux image version, `linux-image-4.4.0-116-generic`.

Has anybody else encountered this problem, and does anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: If you press the left or right arrow key right after grub, what is displayed as the last few lines of the boot log before it hangs?

Comment: Changing `quiet` and `splash` make no difference. It just hangs on a grey screen for a while, no text, then reboots.

Comment: In the end, uninstalling `image-4.4.0-119-generic` and the reinstalling `linux-generic`.

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed the sames issue today. After the question "A new version of boot/grub/menu.lst is available...." you can choice to "keep the local version" or "the package maintainer´s version".

I have tried both options, but either way after the first reboot of UBUNTU OS there is an issue! :(

Also related with upgrade to kernel 4.4.0-119 (but only from 4.4.0-112).

```
"
...
title           Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS, kernel 4.4.0-119-generic
root            (hd0)
kernel          /vmlinuz-4.4.0-119-generic root=LABEL=cloudimg-rootfs ro console=hvc0
initrd          /initrd.img-4.4.0-119-generic

title           Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS, kernel 4.4.0-119-generic (recovery mode)
root            (hd0)
kernel          /vmlinuz-4.4.0-119-generic root=LABEL=cloudimg-rootfs ro  single
initrd          /initrd.img-4.4.0-119-generic

title           Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS, kernel 4.4.0-112-generic
root            (hd0)
kernel          /vmlinuz-4.4.0-112-generic root=LABEL=cloudimg-rootfs ro console=hvc0
initrd          /initrd.img-4.4.0-112-generic

title           Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS, kernel 4.4.0-112-generic (recovery mode)
root            (hd0)
kernel          /vmlinuz-4.4.0-112-generic root=LABEL=cloudimg-rootfs ro  single
initrd          /initrd.img-4.4.0-112-generic
"
```

Answer (score 0):

If we skip the "cloud-init" updates, we still get the question about the /boot/grub/men.lst, but if we choose the first option (maintainer's version) we have no issues anymore!

See also https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=844280&tstart=0